# vertx service discovery with clients not belonging to cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, vert.x, service-discovery

How can the clients can access to service records without being a member in vertx cluster? Thousands of clients need access to services running in vertx cluster. Is there a way to remotely connect to service discovery component?

Comment: How do you do that when the service is member of a Vert.x cluster? Are you using Zookkeeper or Hazelcast, or something else?

Comment: Hazelcast used for clustering.

Comment: Answered in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/lOmssprrYDY